# Inverse within a finite field

Tags: math, cryptography

I'm reading a book about cryptography (I've tried translate the terms from Spanish to English) and I don't understand how calculate the **inverse within this field** (originally the question used the term “body” instead of “field”, since that's a literal translation from languages like Spanish or German).

Encrypting with a monoalphabetic subtitution by pure decimation:

- Equivalences:
- Ci: Letter encrypted
- a: Decimation constant
- Mi: Message no encrypted
- mod: Module operation (we obtain the remainder)
- n: Number of letters in the encryption alphabet
- Spanish alphabet: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWZXY

· Encryption: Ci = a* Mi mod n
For example --> We will encrypt the letter C (C is the position 2, starting from 0) with a=20 and with the Spanish alfhabet (n=27) --> Ci = 20*C mod 27 = 20*2 mod 27 = 13 => N

· Decryption: a^(-1) * Ci mod n

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**

a^(-1) is the inverse of the decimation factor in the body n; in other words: inverse(a, n). I've googled and tried to do some calculations but I don't obtain the correct result ---> inverse(a, n) = inverse(20, 27) = 16 (and the gcd is valid to do it).

For example:

22^(-1) * 13 mod 27 != 16

Comment: [inverse(20,27)=23, not 16](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=20^%28-1%29+mod+27)

Comment: It was 22,27, but OK :D. Perfect. But I don't understand why when I do in Python, C#... "(22^(-1)) % 27" the result isn't 16, but in Wolfram Alpha yes: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=22^%28-1%29+mod+27 Some idea?

Comment: Using ^ will lead to problems. In those programming languages it means something else, and Wolfram Alpha could be interpreting ^-1 a third way.

Comment: The easiest way to invert in a prime order field (if you don't have a specialized function) is to compute `x^(p-2) mod p`. In C# you'd use `BigInteger.ModPow(x, p - 2, p)`

Comment: While there are fields with order 3^3=27, they're not implemented using modular arithmetic. So what you're working in is just a ring not a field. Also note that only elements for which GCD(x, modulus)=1 will have an inverse. e.g. there is no inverse of 3 mod 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the modular (multiplicative) inverse in your example you have to find `x` such that `(22 * x) % 27 == 1`.

There are a [variety of different ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation) you can do this mathematically. Note that in general, an inverse exists only if `gcd(a, n) == 1`.

If you want to write a simple algorithm for your example, try this Python code:

```
def inverse(a, n):
    for x in range(n):
        if (a * x) % n == 1:
            return x
```

This gives:

```
>>> inverse(22, 27)
16

>>> inverse(20, 27)
23
```

As mentioned in the comments below your question, there may well be better functions for computing the modular inverse in existing libraries for your favourite programming language.

Comment: Perfect! But a dubt: Why in cryptography the inverse of a multiply is the "(a * x) mod n == 1" and no the division?

Comment: No problem! To try to answer your question, multiplication and division are essentially the same operation: all you're doing when you find the multiplicative inverse of a number `a` is finding another number `x` such that `a*x == 1`. For example, if `a = 2` we'd normally suggest `x = 1/2` as the inverse. However, we can't choose non-integers in modulo arithmetic. In your example we're restricted to looking for an inverse to `x` from the integers 0, 1, 2, ..., 25, 26. Instead we can choose `x = 14` because `2*14 = 28 = 1 mod 27`, so 14 is the multiplicative inverse of 2 in this case.

Comment: *sorry, that should read: we're restricted to looking for an inverse to `a` from the integers 0, 1, 2, ..., 25, 26.